# How to Creat bash script for this

Tags: linux, bash, termux

I'm using **termux app** to compile my  **c/c++** code. Typing
`g++ [file.cpp] -o [file] and then ./[file]` on mobile every time feels hard to me.
can anyone tell me Linux script that runs with one simple command/word/keyword (something like "alias") to compile and execute the file?

Comment: [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or a bash [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) or [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)

Comment: But, I have no knowledge of bash/Linux.

Comment: Tell me the command that compiles and executes the file with one word.  For example like this : run(keyword) [filename.cpp]

Comment: `I have no knowledge` - No worries, it's easy to change that. You need to learn. `Tell me the command` - you have to "write" that command, put it in a function or in a script, that way the next time you will have to type less. jhnc linked three possible solutions that allow automating/scripting the functionality you are requesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want specifically a bash script for that, try

```
g++ $1.cpp -o $1
./$1
```

Save this as any file name you like, such as `run`.
Then make it executable by typing `chmod +x run` in your terminal.

Now let's say you have a test.cpp with the content below

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Testing...";
    return 0;
}
```

You can simply type `./run test` in your terminal and the result should be

```
Testing...
```

Comment: /run test.cpp
clang-8: error: no such file or directory: 'test.cpp.cpp'
clang-8: error: no input files
./run: line 2: ./test.cpp: Permission denied

Comment: If you have a `test.cpp`, type `./run test` instead.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.